# Fruiting my Mango Tree indoors

Tags: fruit-trees, flowers, fruits, fruit-drop

I have a small mango tree from seed that produces wonderful white flowers. I was wondering if and how I could get some mangofruit from the tree. I live in the Netherlands and the potted mango tree stands on the windowsill. Please take a look at the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: CLOSE-UP FLOWER

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have a mango tree here? The leaves and flowers don't really look like the ones in the [wild](https://www.123rf.com/photo_56919673_flower-mango-tree-plant-fruit-nature.html).

Comment: Yes, I bought the mango from the market and it tasted very sweet!

Comment: Yeah well, I am sure that this is not a mango tree. Sorry. In the Netherlands the seeds are usually not viable, since mango's get radiated. Furthermore, it would take more than 10 years before a real tree would give fruits, and I never seen a mango tree here in the Netherlands giving fruits. The plant looks more like a nightshade, must have been a seed in the potting soil. Be careful with the fruits, they are poisonous.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I am no expert, but these types of white flowers appear to be common for mango trees. I did a simple google search on 'white flowers mango tree'. Please take a look at: https://www.google.com/search?q=white+flowers+mango+tree&safe=strict&client=ms-android-asus-tpin&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxv6LRp6PpAhWByYUKHUM0DhgQ_AUoAXoECA4QAg&biw=360&bih=596

Comment: Did you also compared the leaves with google images? They dont match at all. And read about mango trees on google? It takes commercial trees 7-8 years before they will fruit, indoors it is almost impossible to get them to fruit. May I ask how old your plant is? First year I guess, since this weed is probably an annual. Well, enjoy your plant anyways!

Comment: Now that I look more closely to the plant, it may also be pepper (paprika). Do you by any chance have a close up of a fully opened flower?

Comment: I have added two close-ups of the flower.

Comment: Thank you, it looks very much like bell pepper (paprika), or any other pepper blossom. See [here](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/pepper/pepper-blossoms-falling-off.htm) for example.

Comment: Thanks, I believe you are right. They look very similair. Let's hope the tree produces some peppers instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When grown outdoors, mangoes are pollinated via insects and air  movement (wind); indoors, none of that takes place, so shaking the plant when the flowers open to try to release the pollen so that it reaches the female flowers  increases the chance of fruits forming. Further info here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/grow-baby-mangoes-indoors-94188.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is good to know that I will not need anything else besides the tree itself. I will shake the tree gently and hope for some mangofruits.